# Odoo 16: Inherit stock.warehouse.orderpoint

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I'm kinda new to Odoo.
A little stuck on a task. Is it possible to add logic to the reordering rules. i.e We have two reordering rules. when stock in hand goes below say 50, a PO will be made to an international vendor. If stock goes below say 2, before the previous PO is fulfilled, make a PO to a local vendor. I'm still trying to make sense out of the _prepare_procurement_values function of the stock.warehouse.orderpoint model.

This is the current model:

```py
from odoo import fields, models,api


class ProductSupplierInfo(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.supplierinfo"

    vendor_locality = fields.Selection(
        [("local", "Local"), ("international", "International")],
        string="Locality",
        default="local",
        store=True,
    )


class InheritStockWarehouseOrderpoint(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.warehouse.orderpoint"

    vendor_locality = fields.Selection(
        [("local", "Local"), ("international", "International")],
        string="Locality",
        default="local",
    )

    _sql_constraints = [
        (
            "supplier_locality_check",
            "unique (product_id, vendor_locality)",
            "You can not have more than one supplier from the same locality!",
        ),
        (
            "product_location_check",
            "CHECK(1=1)",
            "A replenishment rule already exists.",
        ),
    ]
```